# XSD any element validation error with CDATA

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have an XSD with an any-element (`<xs:any/>`)

When I create an instance of this XSD and place a CDATA section in it, I get validation errors.

I also tried with attributes like:

```
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"
```

I use XmlSpy for schema validation.

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking if CDATA is valid or not?  Because I don't think it is...

Comment: No, the CDATA holds information that should not be parsed by the XML validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it. I forgot to place an element around the CDATA section!